# Strange extra space between 2 elements?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I try to build a responsive design for a website but have runned in to a problem.

Visit this page : http://test.ufeed.se/

Change your browser size to under 820px and you will see a responsive design. The problem here is that I get a strange space between the data and the title? I have tried to find why there is a space but without luck?

This is the simple markup of the part :

```
<div class="rightPostCell">
        <div class="titleCon">
            <div class="linkIcoCon">
               ...
            </div>
            <div class="floatLeft">
               ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="data dimText">
            <div class="commentsCon">
                ...
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="createdDateCon">
                ...
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="baseLinkCon">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
```

Why is there a space between title and data? And how do I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes you need to make to your ***mobile.css*** file

```
.postContainer .titleCon{
   overflow:hidden; /* ADD this property */
}

.postContainer .data{
   overflow:hidden; /* ADD this property */
   clear:both; /* REMOVE this property */
}
```

Comment: But I need the title to be able to grow and show the content?

Comment: `overflow:hidden` allows elements, with floats inside them, to expand to contain their floated children.. so you *need* to put it so the the container has a calculatable size. (*in other words if you do not specify a fixed height it will not hide anything*)

Comment: @SnowJim, that is how you make an element expand to fit its contents when using floats. you can use `overflow:auto` as well.

Comment: i Uploaded the changes but it did not solve the problem. I have never had to use overflow for a simple structure like this before? There most be a bad markup somewhere?

Comment: the problem is that by not using `overflow:hidden` (*or `auto`*) you do not enclose your floated elements, and when you do the `clear:both` it takes into consideration the image on the left. That is why the texts go below the image always..

Comment: You have now added the `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` elements after the `.titleCon` and after the `.data.dimText`. That is why it fails. Remove those and it should work with the above css

Comment: (*to make it more robust - for the future - you should add `overflow:hidden` to the `li` elements under the `#mainPostList` as well*)

Comment: New version uploaded but the problem is still there when making the browser smaller?

Comment: You have not removed the `clear:both` from the `.postContainer .data` rule. And also add `overflow:hidden` to the `.postContainer` element. In general you need to use `overflow:hidden` to non-floated elements that contain floated children. (*i am making the changes live - with firebug - to your site so i know they work..*)

Comment: I always thought that overflow:hidden meant that the content was hidden if it was not fitted within the container?

Comment: that work for elements that have `height` with a specified value.. otherwise the browser does not know where to start hiding..

Comment: lastly you might want to change the `.floatLeft` to `.floatLeft {float:none;margin-left: 18px;}` for the mobile version

Comment: Why would I like to change the floatLeft class in mobile?

Comment: to keep the title from falling below the icon (*when the browser is very narrow*)

Comment: Thanks, did however not need the float: none and margin-left, just removing the floatleft worked.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's a `float` issue (I find issues tend to crop up every time I use `float`, generally I prefer `display: inline-block` because it introduces fewer bizarre bugs like this) - if I disable `clear: both` on the data, it falls into place correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to remove both the div with clear:both within the div class="data.. element but this did not fix the problem? Exacly what clear:left do you remove to fix the problem?

Comment: Not relevant to this question but `display:inline-block` have it's own issues in old browsers.

Comment: I have updated the only page with your suggestion but that did nothing?

Comment: @Hoshts Yes, `inline-block` has issues in older browsers, but they're very easy to work around (i.e. `zoom:1`). Unlike `inline-block`, float seems to cause issues in *every* browser, unless you're very, very careful with it.

Answer (score 0):

line 37 of your PostList.css
add `overflow:auto`

in mobile.css line 80
change float:none
to `clear:both`

will need to add some margin after that but it removes the space that occurred.

Comment: rightPostCell got overflow:auto in PostList.css and postContainer got clear:both instead of float:none. This generates a vary strange layout with a lot of scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

try this one it will solve your issue
add clear class after left and right cell and add over flow hidden in  `.postContainer .rightPostCell` class

```
<div class="postContainer">
      <div class="leftPostCell">data</div>
      <div class="rightPostCell">data</div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>

.postContainer .rightPostCell {margin-left: 123px;overflow: hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of solutions. Here is one:

**mobile.css line 80**

```
.postContainer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  float: left;
}
```

**PostList.css line 37**

```
.postContainer .rightPostCell {
  float: left;
}
```